# "UID" (unique identifier) - half abbreviation, half initialism. What it is?

Tags: abbreviations, initialisms

According to Your Dictionary¹:

- *Abbreviations*: **St.** for *Street* and *Saint*, **Mr.** for *mister*
- *Acronyms*: **radar** for *radio detection and ranging*
- *Initialisms*: **aka** for *also known as*, **FBI** for *Federal Bureau of Investigation*

The difference between acronymns and initialisms is that acromyms form new words, while initialisms are pronounces letter-by-letter.

People who are familiar with programming, databases, or library science are well familiar with the **ID** abbreviation, which stands for *identifier*.

But there is another one "thing", **UID**, which stands for *unique identifier*. It doesn't look as a pure abbreviation (because there are two words) or a pure initialism (because the first words is trimmed to two letters). So what it is?

¹ https://abbreviations.yourdictionary.com/articles/what-is-the-difference-between-an-abbreviation-and-an-acroynm.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117713/discussion-on-question-by-jsv-uid-unique-identifier-half-abbreviation-hal).

Comment: @tchrist Please make sure that when you move a discussion to the chat, the discussion does not contain anything really helpful or they are long enough to not be automatically deleted. The discussion you have moved is now gone and as far as I remember, there were some helpful comments. I write this because this is not the first time when you moved a useful discussion to the chat and it was disappeared :-/ And of course thank you for your work as moderator.